# Laravel: How to encode special characters stored in DB

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have a small Laravel app that has an angular front-end. I'm feeding some data through to the front-end from the DB by returning json from a DB query.

The DB contains encoded characters stored as, for example: `&quot;`

Is there a way to escape these when the json is generated or maybe on the front-end?

Comment: Do you mean by encoded characters instead of "DB contains escaped characters"?

Comment: Sorry yeah I do. It's been a long day!